# In multiple parachutes, is each offset by a weight/hole?

Tags: apollo-program, identify-this-object, parachute

[image: multiple parachutes]
Source: NASA via [wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_16_Recovery_-_GPN-2000-001503.jpg)

As the image shows, in multiple parachutes, each assumes a position away from the center. The post, [Why don't 3-parachute descent systems collide and collapse?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3473/32596), says it's the air spilling from each that ensures separation (non-vertical alignment).

In the zoom and crop below, there seems to be an offset dark feature on each parachute:

[image]

What is that? (The photo is the Apollo 16 landing.)

Comment: See similar: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/why-dont-3-parachute-descent-systems-collide-and-collapse

Comment: @MarsJarsGuitars-n-Chars: Many thanks. I've now focused on the dark feature.

Comment: It is a keen observation. They certainly appear to be "weights" of some sort, and the arrangement would supply a force to help keep them separated, but I have no documentation for a proper answer.

Comment: Those circular holes in the top portion of the parachute look scary...

Comment: okay I got your comment on the other post, thanks for the update!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those dark objects are the deployment bags which contained the main parachutes prior to inflation.

[image]

Source: [The Apollo Parachute Landing System](https://www.scribd.com/document/49197880/The-Apollo-Parachute-Landing-System)

Also from [Apollo 15 Main Parachute Failure Anomaly Report](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/outreach/SignificantIncidents/assets/apollo-15-mission-anomaly-report-no.-1-main-parachute-failure.pdf)

[image]

> Two 16.5-foot diameter conical ribbon~type drogue parachutes are
>   mortar-deployed 1.6 seconds after forward heat shield jettison. The
>   drogue parachutes are deployed in a reefed condition and, 1O seconds
>   later, inflate to the fully open configuration. The drogue
>   parachutes are released from the command module at an altitude of
>   about 11000 feet. At drogue parachute disconnect three 7.2-foot
>   diameter ring-slot pilot parachutes are mortar-deployed. The pilot
>   parachutes provide the force necessary to release the main parachute
>   retention system and pull the main parachute pack assemblies from the
>   upper deck. **As the main parachute packs are pulled away from the
>   command module, the parachutes are extracted from their deployment
>   bags.** Each main parachute inflates through two reefing stages to the
>   fully open configuration.

(emphasis mine)

I cropped and annotated this Apollo 16 image to show the entire system: pilot chutes, deployment bags, and main canopies.

Red arrows - pilot chutes; Green arrows, deployment bags.

[Image source](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/full_width_feature/public/thumbnails/image/s72-36291.jpg)

[image]

There are no "weights" provided on top of the parachute canopies.